# Efficient parallelization of two tasks

Tags: matlab, parallel-processing

I have two tasks that take a fairly short time to compute (around half a second each). These two tasks (say A and B) are called repeatedly a large number of times. Each time they are called, the two tasks can be computed in parallel because they don't depend on each other. Here is an example code without parallelization:

```
A = 3;
B = 4;

for counter = 1:5000

A = task1(counter,A); %Run task 1
B = task2(counter,B); %Run task 2

disp(task3(A,B)); %Use the results for task 3
end
```

The most obvious way to parallelize this on MATLAB is to do the following:

```
A = 3;
B = 4;

pool = parpool("threads");
for counter = 1:5000

parfor p = 1:2
if p == 1
A = task1(counter,A); %Run task 1
end
if p == 2
B = task2(counter,B); %Run task 2
end

disp(task3(A,B)); %Use the results for task 3
end
delete('pool')
```

This implementation, however, turns out to be much slower (almost by 10 times). My guess is that this is the result of overhead issues involved in parallelization.

Is there any way to go around this?

Comment: What do task1 and task2 do specifically? Maybe there is a way to use built-in MATLAB functions for them that are already multi-threaded in the background.

Comment: Tasks 1 and 2 are independent differential equation solvers. Task 3 dumps some data into a file which tasks 1 and 2 call from within them. Because this is a custom solver, there is no MATLAB in-built function (yet) for 1 and 2.

Comment: Are subsequent iterations of `counter` independent? Looks from this example like it would be better to parallelise that loop instead. Also does `task3` need to depend on both `A` and `B` or could you have `task3a` and `task3b` so there is no race condition waiting on the otherwise-independent `task1` and `task2`?

Comment: This was somewhat sloppy notation from my side. No, the subsequent iterations of counter are NOT independent. And yes, task3 does depend on both A and B at the same time. The only tasks that are independent are task1 and task2

Comment: @Wolfie, I have added some code for improved clarity if that helps

Comment: Your parallel code is not valid. `task1` depends on the previous iteration of `task1`, and therefore cannot be run in parallel. To do parallel processing with a short task, configure your parallel pool to be thread-based, rather than the default process-based. There are fewer things you can do in threads, but there is much less overhead. Process-based parallelism requires spinning up new MATLAB processes, which always takes time.

Comment: To parallelize your two jobs, see `parfeval`.

Comment: @CrisLuengo, task1 does depend on the previous iteration of task1, but task1 and task2 can be executed in parallel. I will look into parfeval

Comment: I misread your code. Proper indentation would have prevented that. First thing to do is set up your parallel pool to use threads. https://www.mathworks.com/help/parallel-computing/choose-between-thread-based-and-process-based-environments.html

Comment: Isn't that what parpool("threads") is already doing?